# How to use ternary expressions by JSX?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I want to use ternary expressions by `JSX` like:

```
<div>
   {isLoading
      ? 'pending...'
      : errorMsg ? errorMsg : <div>something...</div>
   }
</div>
```

but I wonder it can be simple like this, but it does not work

```
<div>
   {isLoading
     ? 'pending...'
     : {errorMsg || (<div>something...</div>)}
   }
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work in the second example because it can't evaluate to something. you are writing ```errorMsg || (<div>something...</div>)}``` But what it means is errorMsg or <div>something...</div>)} it's an error part where code can't evaluate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can write, but remove the `{}`. Reason is, `{}` is required to put the [expressions inside JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx), in other cases, it will mean that you are trying to return an `object`. That's the reason of not working in your case.

Write it like this:

```
<div>
   {isLoading
     ? 'pending...'
     : (errorMsg || (<div>something...</div>))      // no `{}`, otherwise it will be treated an a object
   }
</div>
```